# Pass the Id from Button to timePicker dialog

Tags: android

I have a timePicker dialog, which ca be called from different buttons.
How can I pass the Id from which the dialog is called?

This is the relevant Code:

```
    //Time picker
    private int pHour;
    private int pMinute;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /** Get the current time */
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        pHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        pMinute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
}
```

The click event from the Buttons:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

 // Here I should pass the v.getId() to the dialog
 showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                mTimeSetListener, pHour, pMinute, false);
    }
    return null;
}

/** Callback received when the user "picks" a time in the dialog */
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            pHour = hourOfDay;
            pMinute = minute;
            //Here I should know from which v.getId() the dialog was called
        }
    };
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write your own picker for what you want to do:

Assuming that you have to call the same picker for all buttons, I suggest you to use, `switch` statement on the `Button`'s

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

  switch(v.getId()){

  case R.id.Button1:
       showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
       break;

  case R.id.Button2: 
       showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
       break;
  }
}
```

You can use different `Dialog` ID's in case you want different `Dialog`'s to pop up.

Comment: Thanks.Then I have to have as many Dialogs as Buttons. I thought I can avoid this.

Comment: But how can I select different Callbacks with different Dialog ID's?

Comment: set different listeners in new TimePickerDialog(this,
                mTimeSetListener, pHour, pMinute, false);

Comment: Hi Im using MVP model. So fragment is handling all events. So I cant register multiple listeners is there any other way